# How to call a PHP function in an HTML form as an action to an attachment

Tags: php, html

I have an html form and I have a php function. I need the attachment element in the html form to run through the php function code and then get sent to an email. I need the data to get parsed and then sent to the email. The attachment will be an SPA extension.

Here is the code for the form -

```
    <form METHOD = "POST" action="mailto: abc@xyz.com">
Material : 
<input type ="text" name="material number"/> <br>  

Batch Number:
<input type ="text" name= "batch number"/ > <br> 

Processing Stage: 
<input type ="text" name= "Processing State"/ > <br> 

Analysis: 
<input type= "text" name= "Analysis" /> <br> 

Attachment:
<METHOD="post" ACTION="generatePlotForSPA(attachedfile)" ENCTYPE="multipart/form-data">
<INPUT TYPE="file" NAME="attachedfile" MAXLENGTH=5000 >  <br>
<input type="submit" value="Submit"/> <br> 
</form>
```

Here is the PHP code-

```
<?php

function generatePlotForSPA($source, $targetFile) {

    $sourceFile = fopen($source, "rb");

    fseek($sourceFile, 386);
    $targetOffset = current(unpack("v", fread($sourceFile, 2)));
    if($targetOffset > filesize($source)) {
        return false;
    }
    fseek($sourceFile, 390);
    $dataLength = current(unpack("v", fread($sourceFile, 2)));
    if($dataLength + $targetOffset > filesize($source)) {
        return false;
    }

    fseek($sourceFile, $targetOffset);

    $rawData = fread($sourceFile, $dataLength);
    $rawDataOutputPath = $source . "_raw_data";
    $outputFile = fopen($rawDataOutputPath, "w");
    fwrite($outputFile, $rawData);
    fclose($outputFile);
    $gnuScript = "set terminal png size {width},{height};
        set output '{output}';

        unset key;
        unset border;

    plot '<cat' binary filetype=bin format='%float32' endian=little array=1:0 with lines lt rgb 'black';";

    $targetScript = str_replace("{output}", $targetFile, $gnuScript);
    $targetScript = str_replace("{width}", 500, $targetScript);
    $targetScript = str_replace("{height}", 400, $targetScript);
    $gnuPath = "gnuplot";
    $outputScript = "cat \"" . $rawDataOutputPath . "\" | " . $gnuPath . " -e \"" . $targetScript . "\"";
    exec($outputScript);
    if(!file_exists($targetFile)) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
?>
```

Any suggestions on how to connect the two

Comment: Create one form, and process both the email-sending through PHP, and the file-handling, in the same file. And frankly, calling that HTML-code "html5" is quite arrogant. You're lacking proper semantics, no `<label>`s, no `<fieldsets>` either... (granted, the latter isn't needed, but... yeah). And you can't have multiple methods and actions in the same form.

Answer (score 0):

you need to call the php file in `action="the_php_file.php"`
then include the mail to action in the file itself

Answer (score 0):

function call in html form action is the feature of object oriented php . you cant use it in raw php ..
you can do this below .

at first create 2 file
1- something.php
2- processing.php

than make the form in something.php
and give the action like

```
<form METHOD = "POST" action="processing.php">
```

and than put the php code in processing.php file .
receive all the values from the form input field by

```
$name = $_POST['name'];
```

and user php mailto function to send the mail in the email address and you can do anything with the data you received..